# Laravel factory does not load global scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-scopes

I cannot figure out why global scope isn't loading with the factory during the tests:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //...

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     */
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new PreviousLogin);
    }

    /**
     * Get Audit relationship.
     */
    public function previousLogin(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Audit::class);
    }
}
```

```
class PreviousLogin implements Scope
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void
    {
       $builder->addSelect([
            'previous_login_id' => Audit::select('id')
                ->whereColumn('user_id', 'users.id')
                ->where('event', UserLoggedIn::class)
                ->latest()
                ->skip(1)
                ->take(1),
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Render view.
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        $previousLogin = $request->user()->previousLogin;

        return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Index', [
            'previous_login' => [
                'date' => $previousLogin?->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'),
                'ip' => $previousLogin?->ip_address,
                'agent' => $previousLogin?->agent,
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function renders_view_and_displays_previous_login(): void
{
    $audit = Audit::factory()->create([
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->subHour(),
    ]);

    $this->actingAs(User::factory()->create())
        ->get(route('dashboard'))
        ->assertInertia(fn(AssertableInertia $page) => $page
            ->has('previous_login', fn(AssertableInertia $page) => $page
                ->where('date', $audit->created_at->formated('d/m/Y H:i:s'))
                ->where('ip', $audit->ip_address)
                ->where('agent', $audit->agent)
                ->etc()
            )
        );
}
```

When debugging I'm getting:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MissingAttributeException: The attribute [previous_login_id] either does not exist or was not retrieved for model [App\User\Models\User].